# How to move git origin/master

Tags: git, github, branch, sourcetree

Git is driving me mad. I forked a github repo and added some changes, then realised that I had made my changes on top of some commits after master.

In my local copy of the repo, I reset `master` back to `upstream/master` and then cherry picked the changes. Like this:

[image: Git stuff]

My change is "Add support for directed advertising mode". As you can see I accidentally did it on top of `upstream/scheduling_policy` instead of `upstream/master`.

```
The problem is when I try and push this, I get this error:

git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false push -v --tags --set-upstream origin master:master
Pushing to https://github.com/Timmmm/ble.git
To https://github.com/Timmmm/ble.git
... lots of [up to date]s ...
 = [up to date]      v2.5.2 -> v2.5.2
 = [up to date]      v2.6.0 -> v2.6.0
 = [up to date]      workingOldBootloader -> workingOldBootloader
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
```

Can someone tell me the totally intuitive command that I need to make it move the `origin/master` branch to my local `master` branch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah I think the reason for the cryptic error "non-fast-forward" is that Git is worried that I'll lose the `origin/master` commit if I move it, since no other branches point to that.

You can tell Git that you actually want that by using a force push:

```
git push -f
```

Unfortunately this [isn't implemented in SourceTree](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/54469/how-do-i-perform-a-forced-push-push-f-from-sourcetree) for reasons that nobody has even tried to explain (it's "dangerous", "always a mistake" and "not what you want").

Answer (score 1):

Try to `merge` branch **origin/master** to **master**

Comment: Nope that didn't work at all. It just brought the three purple commits onto my local master (which I don't want), and `origin/master` stayed where it was. How do I undo that? Does git even have undo?

Comment: Ah nm I managed to undo it by resetting `master` to the previous commit.

Comment: Why don't you want to merge if the changes are the same as on your origin/master and you already made them on your local master? You could merge and then resolve any merge conflicts so you are sure that your changes are correct.